# Problems with db.transaction on phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, web-sql

I have a function that save some data to my database and all worked fine on cordova 2.4, but I upgraded to cordova 2.6 and I started to have some issues with my database, it becames slow and start to have some problems with callbacks.

**My first problem** is that the callback given to db.transaction fires when I call tx.executeSql

```
function populateDB(tx) {
     tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO'); /* <-- succesCB is fired */
     tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)'); /* <-- succesCB is fired again */
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")'); /* <-- succesCB is fired again */
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")'); /* <-- succesCB is fired again */
}

function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
}

var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
```

Before the upgrade it was fired at the end of the transaction function (in this case populateDB), on chrome is fired at the end too.

Wich is the right behavior? Fired on executeSql or at the end of populateDB ?

I have the same behavior on Galaxy S2 (4.1.2), Asus Transformer TF101 (4.0.3), Galaxy Tab (4.0.4)

My second problem is that when I'm inserting all my data it take ages, about 5min for 13 000 records I have tried to insert values like `INSERT INTO mytable (id, x) VALUES (1, "sas"), (2, "dsfdsf"), ...` and it was much faster, but it only works when using sqlite >= 3.7.11, so I tried the UNION SELECT pattern but is really slow.

some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure your problem, but I see couple of issue.

WebSQL versioned opening is broken. Suggested opening process is open without version and then use version change transaction, as follow

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", '', "Cordova Demo", 200000)
if (db.version != '1.0') {
   db.versionChange(...)
}
```

Another one is reuse tx from request callback.

```
tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO', [], function (t, r) {
  t.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
});
```

From your code, tx execution is not orderred. Browser can execute all four of then in any order.

Regarding two `window.openDatabase`, one is browser native (if supported) and another is polyfill by phonegap via plugin.

Comment: Thanks is good to know all this stuff but it didn't solve my problem.  A cordova (phonegap) [developer](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3047) told me that the problem is because android 4.0 uses shim on webSQL, but I still think t'is a bug, because on cordova 2.5 it works and in cordova 2.6 it doesn't. I will take my time to look in to cordova files and find out the differences.

Comment: Why not try out my database library https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Its better you use html5 database instead of phonegap's database.

Comment: the problem here is that both have are called exactly in the same way  `window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000)`